# Fix redirection after submit discount code

Tags: woocommerce

I am using *"[Display a WooCommerce coupon input field anywhere with a shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247087/display-a-woocommerce-coupon-input-field-anywhere-with-a-shortcode/55247652#55247652)"* answer code to add a coupon form on my homepage (via a shortcode).

It works but I've got a problem with the redirection after input the value.

The code runs on this path: `www.nameofthesite.com/folder/`but the redirection is on `www.nameofthesite.com` instead of `www.nameofthesite.com/folder/` after validation…

Any help Is welcome.

Comment: Sorry but there is no redirection on this code… I have tested it on different pages and sub pages, there is no redirection, the current page is always reloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Loic. You can test the site at this url : https://www.netao.website/garrec/ After enter the code, the site is redirect to : https://www.netao.website/ . If you reload with the good URL (https://www.netao.website/garrec/), the code is active. I miss something…

Comment: Code to test : 4321