# Display a WooCommerce coupon input field anywhere with a shortcode and check the value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, coupon

I want to use this input field. but also that the value will be calculated if the value has been calculated is the option to apply the coupon on the checkout page

I'm using [Display a WooCommerce coupon input field anywhere with a shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247652/11987538) answer code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a WooCommerce coupon input field anywhere with a shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247087/display-a-woocommerce-coupon-input-field-anywhere-with-a-shortcode)

Comment: no because I'm using that shortcode now. I just want one more step in between.

If the coupon is entered first show the value of the coupon and then give the customer the option to apply it on the checkout page